# encoding in py_compile vs import

Tags: python-2.7, encoding, compilation, python-import

When a python script with non ASCII character is compiled using py_compile.compile it does not complaint about encoding. But when imported gives in python 2.7

`SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe2' in file`

Why is this happening? whats the difference between importing and compiling using py_compile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that Python provides two variants of its lexer, one used internally when Python itself parses files, and one that is exposed to Python through e.g. `__builtins__.compile` or `tokenizer.generate_tokens`. Only the former one checks for non-ASCII characters, it seems. It's controlled by an `#ifdef PGEN` in Parser/tokenizer.c.

I have a qualified guess on why they did it this way: In Python 3, non-ASCII characters are permitted in .py files, and are interpreted as utf-8 IIRC. By silently permitting UTF-8 in the lexer, 2.7's `tokenizer.generate_tokens()` function can accept all valid Py3 code.